# How to make a TP-Link CPE 710 work with Asus RT-AX86U with LACP / WAN Aggregation / 802.3ad?

Tags: networking, router, link-aggregation

I currently have a Primary WAN, and a Secondary WAN with speeds of 150mbps and 300mbps respectively.

I use my Primary one as the main WAN (which is connected from a bridged ISP modem) and doesnt need any other configuration from the Asus Router modem.

My Secondary WAN (which is coming from CPE710) which is unstable but fast, is receiving a fast wireless internet from another access point a hundred meters away.

Now, I already enabled the WAN Aggregation on my Asus router, but my problem is that the CPE 710 doesnt seem to support LACP. Is there any other way I could make the CPE 710s WAN output work with the Asus router which requires 802.3ad support?. Like an extra hardware or a specific firmware that needs to be installed?.

I also tried doing dual WAN on the Asus router and just did load balancing but it sucks as I could not make use of the aggregate speeds of the two WAN links. So I'm left with WAN Aggregation feature to actually take advantage of the combined speeds. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my god, I was scratching my head alot just trying to aggregate my internet connection into one internet connection. But apparently, the Dual WAN feature of the Asus router would have been more than enough to do the job for me with some caveats like not being able to take advantage of the network monitoring features and the like and others that I may have just not noticed yet. But for now, this will do it for me. I will try to do the WAN Aggregation feature later on just to take of this cons on doing it on dual WAN. Anyhow, this is how I did it.

After enabling Dual WAN feature on the Asus Router, just set the Load Balance ratio to 1:1. I initially set this to 3:1 hence I was not able to get the aggregate speeds of my network. But when I set it to 1:1, I could now get the speeds of my 2 internet connections in one device!

The speed of my primary Wan is 150Mbps DL to 150-300Mbps UL

The speed of my secondary WAN which is a free public wifi by the government in my area is 100-200MbpsDL to 100-250Mbls UL. Unstable in speed, stable in ping but free for 5-8 hours a day.

And my speed test on a single computer is now with the aggregate speeds of the two WANs
Reaching 300-400MbpsDL to 350-600Mbps+ UL. Indicating that the two WANs speed has finally combined for general use.

Speedtest.net
[image]

Fast.com
[image]

Actual Download speed with IDM
[image]

Remarks:
I was even testing this via WiFi, testing this directly in the router I am getting over 400MbpsDL and 500-600MbpsUL. Indicating that I was able to aggregate the speeds of my home connection and the free public wifi in my area.

In the mean time, it would be great to have the WAN aggregation work since this would allow me to automatically balance the network speeds and at the same time do failover with LACP really, and at the same time take advantage of the network monitoring and security features offered in the router. But for now, this  Dual WAN with Load Balance works for me for aggregating the network speeds. I'll update this answer later on if I found other remove features on the router with Dual WAN on.

Additional info:
On a single connection, I am only able to max out either of the two connections and not aggregate both speeds. But if primary wan is already maxed out, I could still use the remaining bandwidth from the secondary WAN to download more without using the maxedout bandwidth of the primary wan, something which is bearable enough for me as its still works like an aggregated speed on my single computer. I just havent tried this on torrents yet which does peer downloads, afterall, I can't find a torrent that would allow me to fully utilize the 300-500mbps DL speed I could potentially get on both connections. But on speedtest with multiple connections allowed, it definitely shows the aggregate speeds of WANs.

Answer (score 0):

> I also tried doing dual WAN on the Asus router and just did load balancing but it sucks as I could not make use of the aggregate speeds of the two WAN links

802.3ad (LACP) won't work in your situation – it cannot be used to combine links that go to completely different devices. It can only aggregate identical connections between the *same* two endpoints (e.g. you could combine 4x100Mbps Ethernet links between a router and a modem), making them appear like a single link – though still not quite giving you the combined speed anyway.

But even if it *could* be used to combine links that go to different devices, that's not where your real problem is at all.

As long as you have two different IP addresses from separate ISPs, it's more or less unavoidable that you won't get the "aggregate" speed for a single download Any single connection will be made from one IP address, through one WAN link, and therefore downloaded data will come back to that same IP address through the same *one* WAN link – inbound routing is beyond your control, so you can't make ISPs send you half the data through a completely different path than what the IP address says.

As far as I know, the only way to download something at the combined 450 Mbps speed would be to use a parallel download (i.e. multiple TCP connections, each downloading a different part of the file), making sure that your WAN load-balancer selects different uplinks every time.

Comment: I think that multiple TCP connections is being done thru IDM(Internet Download Manager) as that one downloads multiple parts of a file for faster download speeds afaicr. EItherway, it would really be best at the very least that on one device, if I am maxing out the single connection of the primary wan, it would switch to the secondary wan. I don't need to make the entire 400mbps+ work on a single session but at best work on different connections on a single device. Wont LACP allow for the use of multiple WAN connections for different activities on a single device?.

Comment: No, it won't. What you're asking for is the complete opposite of what LACP does.